# Mongo / Mongoose How to use virtuals to count issued reset token?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, virtual

When a user wants to reset password, I issu a reset token and when he does set it to undefined. I want a user to only be able to request that 3 times a day. I dont want to add a count property but only use virtual and.not sure how to do that

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  resetToken: String
});

userSchema.virtual('checkMaxCountOfPwdResets').get(function() {
   let count = 0;
   count =+ 1
    return count;
})
```

then before issuing a reset token, I would call checkMaxCountOfPwdResets to see if count is more than 3.